# Understanding Angular 6 services

Tags: angular

I'm trying to understand how services work in Angular.

I have a module called `CardModule` which has the following definition:

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
   CommonModule
   BrowserAnimationsModule
   MatMenuModule
 ]
 declarations: [
   CardStackComponent
   UnitCardComponent
   SimplecardComponent
 ]
 providers: [
   CardService
 ]
 exports: [
   CardStackComponent
   SimplecardComponent
 ]
})
export class CardsModule { }
```

As you can see it is providing `CardService`  along with some other components like `SimplecardComponent` . I have a second "consumer" module which wants to use `SimplecardComponent`  like so,

```
imports: [
   CommonModule,
   CardsModule
 ],
 declarations: [
   SomeComponent
 ],
 providers: [],
 exports: [
   SomeComponent
 ]
export class SharedModule {}
```

So, I've imported `CardsModule` here to be able to use `SimplecardComponent`  in this module. Now, I'd like to also use the provided `CardService`  in the declared `SomeComponent` . How can I do this?

I feel like importing the `CardService` directly in the `SharedComponent` like

```
import { CardService } from '<path to card-service.ts>';
```

nullifies the whole point of putting it in `CardsModule` .

Is there no other way of doing this other than directly accessing the path to `card-service.ts`?

If not, what then is the point of saying that the `CardsModule` provides the `CardService`?

Comment: If you want to inject a service in the constructor of a component you must import the service in component.ts (equal if you want to use a interface, or any declaration). When a Module provide a Service, this service is common (there are a unique instance) for all the components in the module or component in modules that was imported. In your case you have an unique "cardService" that can use in CardStackComponent, UnitCardComponent, SimplecardComponent and SomeComponent

Comment: That makes sense now. What I'm trying to know is how do I scope a service, in this case CardService, so that it can never be used unless CardModule is imported?

Further, once I do import CardModule in SharedModule, is there no other way to access CardService in SomeComponent except referencing its path?